# Why doesn't android intent work the first time?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-button

I have an android app with two activites, `MainActivity` is the start screen of the app which has a button which starts an intent to go to `CameraActivity`, the code to do this is:

```
startButton = findViewById(R.id.button_start);
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

However when I start the app and begin on `MainActivity` and click on `startButton`, the app sends me directly back to `MainActivity` again. After this, on the second attempt of clicking `startButton` on the re-created `MainActivity`, I am redirected to `CameraActivity`.

In the logs, I can see that, on the first click of `startButton`, it attempts to open `CameraActivity` but falls back to `MainActivity` and on the second attempt, it opens `CameraActivity` successfully.

The logs for the first attempt of clicking `startButton` is [here](https://pastebin.com/E8eB9YGx) and the second attempt is [here](https://pastebin.com/iqg8MKuj).

Comment: where do you set your `onClickListener` ? Can you provide your `CameraActivity` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have some problems with second activity which is `CameraActivity.java`? Maybe that's why it is opens only after second try (after crash or smth.). Add after `startActivity(i);` method call `finish();` and look what will happen. Double check your `CameraActivity.java` and `Manifest.xml`

Also why do you use `getApplicationContext()` in `new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ...);`? If you are call it in `Activity` you should  use `ActivityName.this`

Comment: Thank you! Calling `finish()` after `startActivity(i)` was what was necessary, I am guessing that there is something to do with it trying to grab focus back again after triggering the intent

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Considering startButton in your MainActivity, try putting 'MainActivity.this' instead of 'getApplicationContext()'

```
startButton = findViewById(R.id.button_start);
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Secondly, make sure there is no extra intents in CameraActivity class which is redirecting you to main activity. Kindly remove them if any and finish the CameraActivity class instead using following code,

```
someBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CameraActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice